# Get objectId of created book and store in a column in author using Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I would like to store a objectId as a pointer.

```
//This is supposed to get the objectId of the book
- (IBAction)clickEnterpilensgard:(id)sender {
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"books"];

[query includeKey:@"objectId"];

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *allBookids, NSError *error) {
    for (PFObject *getoneId in allBookids) {
        bookIdString = getoneId[@"objectId"];
        NSLog(@"retrieved related post: %@", bookIdString);
    }
}];
}
```

Here i want to update a column in Author "mybook" as the object ID i get from the above code

```
    PFQuery *updatemybook = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"User"];

// Retrieve the object by id
[updatemybook getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"xWMyZ4YEGZ" block:^(PFObject *updatethebook, NSError *error) {

    updatethebook[@"myBook"] = bookIdString;

}];
```

This is the error code i get:

2014-09-07 14:38:15.974 MyApp[8397:90b] retrieved related post: (null)
2014-09-07 14:38:15.974 MyApp[8397:90b] retrieved related post: (null)
2014-09-07 14:38:16.072 MyApp[8397:90b] Error: no results matched the query (Code: 101, Version: 1.2.20)

Edited: I manage to get it working!!
Inside the "getObjectInBackgroundWithId:" I used this piece of code:

```
NSString *storeId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", gameScore.objectId];
NSLog(@"Id: %@", storeId);
```

Comment: So is that method getting a known entry from parse?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `getObjectWithId` for this instead.  That will solve your problem.

But let me make a suggestion.  I would use a relation column type instead of pointer because that is most likely what you are trying to do.

I would take a look at the API Documentation because it is really helpful and would have solved your problem quite quickly.  The guide is super helpful as well.

https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/getObjectWithId:

https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#objects/iOS